# ¿Por qué esta operación devuelve 0 y no 2?

Tags: javascript

¿Por qué cuando hago esta operación en JavaScript

```js
let num = 332
let ud = num - num / 10 * 10
console.log(ud)
```

`ud` es igual a 0 y no 2?

Comment: Si amigo.......

Comment: ¿Por qué debería devolver 2?

Comment: `let ud = num % 10`...

Comment: ud = num – num / 10 * 10
ud = 332 – 332 / 10 * 10
ud = 332 – 33 * 10
ud = 332 – 330
ud = 2

Comment: Tu actual código equivale a calcular `0 / 100`, por eso da `0`. Explica qué es lo que debe hacer el código.

Comment: Según el orden en que se realizan las operaciones primero debería comenzar con la división, luego con la multiplicación y después con la resta...

Comment: Sí, pero sin obviar los decimales...

Comment: todo numero dividido ente Cero da cero y cero multiplicado entre cualquier otro da Cero

Comment: Lo que realmente quiero que ocurra es obtener el ultimo dígito del 332, pero no quiero usar el .length ni ese tipo de cosas

Comment: Si hermano, y gracias! Pero lo que estoy viendo por sus respuesta es que el orden de operaciones es de izquierda a derecha sin importar si hay multiplicaciones o divisiones

Comment: No @JesusMedina . `ud = num – num / 10 * 10`;  `ud = 332 – 332 / 10 * 10`; `ud = 332 – 33.2 * 10`; `ud = 332 – 332`; `ud = 0`.

Comment: Hola @JesusMedina, intuyo por tu lógica, que eres programador de java (u otro similar), en java, sucedería lo que tu piensas (si java recibe dos int para dividir, devuelve un **int**, capando los decimales), pero como te remarcó en dos ocaciones **padaleiana**, javascript te devuelve el valor **con decimales**, por lo tanto dividir por 10 y luego multiplicar por 10, te devuelve el numero original.

Comment: Si tu pregunta era como obtener el ultimo digito de un numero, porque no preguntaste eso???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu operación:

```
num - num / 10 * 10
```

Básicamente sería lo mismo que:

```
num - ((num / 10) * 10)
```

En donde:

- Primero se hace la división `num / 10`, en donde esto sería `332 / 10` y da como resultado `33.2`.
- Luego sigue la multimplicación `... * 10`, en donde esto sería `33.2 * 10` y da como resultado `332`.
- Y por último, se hace la resta `num - ...`, en donde esto sería `332 - 332` y da como resultado `0`.

---

En pocas palabras, tu función siempre te va a retornar `0` ya que primero se ejecuta la multiplicación y/o división, en donde primero divides entre `10` y luego multiplicas por `10`, dando como resultado el mismo número, y al final restas el número con el mismo número, y siempre te va a dar `0`.

---

Existen muchas formas para obtener el último dígito de un número, pero más sencillo sería utilizar el operador `%`. Con este operador devuelves el resto de la división de dos números, lo que significa que si se usa el número `10` como el segundo operando, el resultado será el último dígito del número quien le haces esa división. Ejemplo:

```js
let num = 332;
let ud = num % 10;
console.log(ud);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas y tiempo compañeros!

Answer (score 8):

Es porque sucede lo siguiente:

1. Se divide `num` sobre 10.
2. La razón (división) se multiplica por diez,
   dando así lo mismo que el anterior valor.
3. Dado que el anterior valor es igual al valor al cual se
   va a restar da 0, porque: `numIgual - numIgual = 0`.

Se utiliza un operador especial `%` (módulo) que sirve para hallar el residuo de una división.

Ejemplo:

```
let number = 332;
let residue = number % 10;
console.log(residue); // print 2.
```

Comment: +1 tanto por responder a la pregunta como por ofrecer una alternativa.

Comment: Mmm no es igual a la mía (?... pero +1 por la explicación :)

Comment: @Cris223511.dev nope, ya que tu respuesta no explica por qué no da ese resultado (? Igual es cierto lo que dice A. Cedano en su respuesta.

Comment: Que algo es bueno no significa que no puede mejorar.

Answer (score 5):

Si el número es **negativo** las respuestas dadas no funcionarán. Deberás usar [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) para obtener el valor absoluto del número si interesa el valor sin importar el signo.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let negativeNumber = -332;
let lastNegative = Math.abs(negativeNumber) % 10;
console.log(`En el caso negativo, el último dígito es: ${lastNegative}`);

let positiveNumber = 332;
let lastPositive = Math.abs(positiveNumber) % 10;
console.log(`En el caso positivo, el último dígito es: ${lastPositive}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

En Javascript no hay distinción de tipos numéricos como en otros lenguajes. Solo existe el tipo [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#number_encoding).

El tipo `Number` está codificado bajo el formato de doble precisión binario de 64 bits IEEE 754. En otras palabras, es equivalente a un `double` precisión de lenguajes cómo C# y Java.

Como este tipo puede representar un subconjunto finito suficientemente grande de números reales, a efectos prácticos se puede entender como un número real.

En los reales, a diferencia de los enteros, la división es cerrada. Entonces, como la multiplicación y la división son operaciones inversas, obtienes el número original si haces ambas a la vez.

La resta es equivalente a sumar el opuesto. Por [propiedad de la  suma](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operaci%C3%B3n_(matem%C3%A1tica)#Propiedades_de_las_operaciones), al sumar un número con su opuesto aditivo obtienes 0.

---

Puedes verificarlo imprimiendo el valor de `num / 10`.

```js
let num = 332
console.log(num / 10)
console.log(num / 10 * 10)
```

Para obtener el resultado división de enteros basta con usar la función [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) sobre la división. Así:

```js
let num = 332
console.log(Math.floor(num / 10))
```

Lo que hace esa función es redondear hacia abajo.

En tu algoritmo, lo aplicarías así:

```js
let num = 332
let ud = num - Math.floor(num / 10) * 10
console.log(ud)
```

Answer (score 0):

esto seria la solucion utilizando el  Math.floor

```js
let num = 332;
let ud = num - Math.floor(num / 10) * 10;
console.log(ud);
```